# if for length of digits in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a textbox and a search button in a form and I want to enter number in the textbox and when I click the button, if the number is equal or bigger than 3 digits, the search button load it's function,and if the enter number is one or two digits, alert an error. how can I write this function?Here is my search function:

```
function search() {   
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "image/"+ cpersoneli.value+".jpg";  
    img.id='img1';
    document.getElementById("img1").appendChild(img);    
    }
```

Comment: You can validate search box value with formik and yup validation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="digits">
<button onclick="search()">Search</button>


function search() {   
    var numberEntered = document.getElementById('digits').value;
    if(numberEntered.length < 3) {
       alert('Error message');
    } else {

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "image/"+ cpersoneli.value+".jpg";  
    img.id='img1';
    document.getElementById("img1").appendChild(img);    
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I have another question. I want in this function,img occur once

Comment: By image occuring once, I hope you mean that you want to get rid of the last appended images. If that's the question, then this is what you can do :  document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML = " ";  document.getElementById("img1").appendChild(img);

Answer (score 0):

you can write like below. I am assuming the number value as mention in description.

```
function search() {  
    //Get number from text box, with id n1
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value);
    if(n<3){
    alert("You message");
    return false;
    } 
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "image/"+ cpersoneli.value+".jpg";  
    img.id='img1';
    document.getElementById("img1").appendChild(img);
```

}

If, you need length of number as mentioned in title then use below if condition without parseInt

```
if(n.length<3){
        alert("You message");
        return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write another function that you can call on button click and add an if condition to call search function.

```
<input type="text" id="txtNumber" />
<button onclick="myFunction()"></button>

function myFunction(){
        let number = document.getElementById('txtNumber').value;
        if(number.length >= 3)
            search()
        else
            alert('Entered number is incorect');
    }
```